# How to locally access remotely launched docker app?

Tags: docker

I run docker container with app by `docker-compose` on a remote machine. I can open this app in browser by typing `http://localhost`. But when I try to do it on the local machine by typing in browser `remoteip:80` it doesn't work.

`docker-compose ps` on remote machine says

```
name command_name Up 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp
```

Remote machine is a VPS with public IP. I opened port 80 using `ufw allow 80`

How can I access the remote docker web app via local browser?

Comment: What is the ip address of the remote machine? It it on the same network as your local machine, or somewhere else? If somewhere else, does it have a publicly accessible address? Does it have a local firewall that might reject connections on port 80? Are there any intervening firewalls that might introduce some restrictions?

Comment: @larsks Added more information